# How to Add favicon and page title on to a asp.net page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, favicon, page-title

I have aspx page like picture :
[image]

I want to favicon and page title on this page. I learned this : favicon and page title inside in <`head>` tag. I tried something but I didn't. I get many error.
How can I do (Without disturbing the code) any idea please ?

I added on .cs code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Title = "Title";
}
```

//I get this error : Using the Title property of Page requires a header control on the page. (e.g. )

Comment: @eagle Please share your actual code, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the code you've shown, you can add any head tags you need to the `UxContentHead` content section:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="UxContentHead" runat="server">
      <!-- meta tags ... -->
      <title>My Page Title</title>
      <link rel="icon" 
            type="image/png" 
            href="http://example.com/myicon.png" />
      <link rel="shortcut icon" 
            type="image/png"
            href="http://example.com/myicon.png"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I added title but nothing changed. I have GlobalMaster.Master page and this page contains title as the following:
`<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>PM</title>
</head>` and still view this title 'PM' @JLRishe

Comment: @eagle If your masterpage already contains a title, you would need to remove it in order to be able to specify one on a specific page.